# is before_create called if there is an error in the validations before it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was able to find the order the callbacks are kicked off [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#available-callbacks/) but it does not say if it is dynamic (if self.errors.any? stop callback chain). Does anyone know if before_create is called only if all validations are passed? Or have any links for in depth walk through on this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial hunch is correct. `before_create` is only called if validations pass. This is easily observed in your original link by looking at the callback lifecycle:

```
before_validation
.  <----- validations happen here
after_validation
before_save
before_create
around_create <--- save happens in here
after_create
after_save
```

If at any point a callback, validations, or save fail, then the later parts of the validate/save cycle are not run.

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed. Guess I need to start reading and stop skimming.